# Downgrade (rollback) Joomla Versions

Tags: joomla-3.x, upgrade, administration, versions

Is is possible to downgrade Joomla versions, for example from version 3.4.3 to 3.4.1?

I know restoring from a backup is the easiest and most efficient way, however is there an alternative?

I have ran into a few issues since upgrading to Joomla 3.4.3 and I would like to 'rollback' just to rule out any possible conflicts etc.

Having read a few tutorials online there doesn't seem to be any clear instructions, they all differ.

I have downloaded a clean installation of Joomla 3.4.1 and set it up locally on xampp - not sure where to go from here. Do I simply copy the 3.4.3 files into the root directory or does the db need to change?

Also what about my modules/plugins/components/template..?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if you can share the issues you have with 3.4.3, we may be able to help you solve those. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Quick Dirty Method:

Take a backup of your Joomla 3.4.3 site and set it up on your localhost. Once done, download the [Joomla 3.4.1 Update Package](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/download/3.4.1/Joomla_3.4.1-Stable-Update_Package.zip) and extract it in the root directory. Don't worry about Database changes as there haven't been any since 3.4.0.

### Long method:

- Install a fresh copy of [Joomla 3.4.1](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/download/3.4.1/Joomla_3.4.1-Stable-Full_Package.zip)
- Re-download and install all 3rd party extensions
- Import the database from your Joomla 3.4.3 site

---

#### Notes

Joomla has not really need designed to be rolled back, therefore with the above, I can't guarantee there won't be any issues but it's these are the only methods I know of.

Personally, I would refrain from rolling back and try the figure out the issues you're having with your 3.4.3 site.